# sdcard performance bottleneck

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, fat32, removable-media

I have loaded my 4 GB FAT32 sdcard almost entirely with mp3 files. Now, I cannot remove none of them because "discovering items" never ends. Even command line tools last forever, including `format e:`. I had to cancel the format after 24 hours of waiting (sdcard reader was blinking) but the card is still readable and all files are at the place as if there was no attempt to format it.

Is such behavior expected? What is the limiting factor of sdcard performance and how do I improve it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Nifle Do you mean that this is expected behaviour? Are SDCards write-once devices? If so, I would like to ask, why don't file managers try to fulfill the operation instead just reporting me that immediately? Why don't you see any problems with behaviour that I describe? Is it expected? Why and what can I do to make my card more responsive?

Comment: You seem to have figured it out yourself what I meant. Thank you for  adding an `answerable question` to your `question`.

Comment: Does it work if you try to delete just a few files at a time?

Comment: @Nifle It will never end removing even a single file.

Comment: Have you check the write-protect switch on the sd card?

Comment: @smc Do you mean that file management tools do wait until somebody switches the write-protection rather than report read-only access offhand? What is point of that? I cannot switch that switch while card is attached to PC and tools respond immediatly when write-protection is on.